# SwiftUI How can I disable line deletion using swipe?

Tags: swiftui

I am using Xcode 11.1 with SwiftUI.

I implemented List delete and sort functions with the following code.

How can I disable line deletion using swipe?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fruits = ["Apple",  "Orange",  "Banana"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit)
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }

    func delete(offsets: IndexSet) {
        fruits.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }

    func move(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
        fruits.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `.deleteDisabled(_ isDisabled:)` modifier. But you have to consider that the return type of this modifier is `View`, not `Text`. So it has a little complexity to implement.
You can use this sample:

1. Create a `CellView` like this:

```swift
struct CellView: View {
    var title: String
    var isDeletable: Bool

    var body: some View {
        return Text(title).deleteDisabled(!isDeletable)
    }
}
```

You can design your cell using `VStack`s, `HStack`s and so on, but you should consider using this modifier on the parent of this hierarchy. Like shown below:

```swift
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    .deleteDisabled(!isDeletable)
}
```

2. After that you can use it in your `ForEach` like below:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fruits = ["Apple",  "Orange",  "Banana"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit -> CellView in
                    if fruit == "Orange" {
                        return CellView(title: fruit, isDeletable: true)
                    } else {
                        return CellView(title: fruit, isDeletable: false)
                    }
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }

    func delete(offsets: IndexSet) {
        fruits.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }

    func move(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
        fruits.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.
Thanks to that, I was able to explain how to disable the delete function for each item.
By the way, is there no way to disable only swipe deletion?
I don't want to accidentally delete it when not in edit mode.

Comment: @capibara You can add a `@Environment(\.editMode) var mode` to observe Edit Mode. Then you can access its wrapped value like this: `self.mode?.wrappedValue` then you may decide whether to show deletable cell or not deletable cells using conditionals.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.
I will try that way.

Comment: `.deleteDisabled(!self.editMode.isEditing)` works exactly the way I want :) thx